# Problem with onClick in React. On desktops works very well, on mobile doesnt work

Tags: android, reactjs, events, mobile, onclick

just like up, i have problem with onClick it doesnt work on mobile.

```
{buttonSkills.map((item, i) =>
   <Button key={i} variant={item.variant} onClick={() => filterIcons(`${item.className}`)}>{item.name}</Button>
)}
```

you may see this *https://retupk.github.io/presentation/#/*

click F12 and see that on mobile buttons ("Wszystko", "Front-End" etc..) in section skills at the very bottom doesnt work

here is full code of my skills section: *https://github.com/RetupK/presentation/blob/master/src/containers/skills/Skills.js*

Anybody know why my onClick doesnt work on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a container with the following css over the entire page, which gets all the click events:

```
.header-main-container {
z-index: 9999
}
```

If you'll remove it you clicking would work.